# Show compose SMS view in Android

Tags: android, sms

I want to send a sms with Android.

What is the intent for SMS sending?

I want to show the compose sms view with my pre-define text passing over in message field.

Comment: You should read [this acticle](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) for full story.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Comment: @toobsco42: No, you are doing the exact oposite. You are sending SMS _yourself_ and this question calls for _via standard SMS application_.

Comment: You may support Dual-Sim devices as well, see this :http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677542/2267723

Comment: This article easy explains SMS/MMS on Android, provides simply code example for sending SMS and receiving SMS: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1044639/Android-SMS-MMS-API-Sending-SMS-MMS-Receiving-SMS

Comment: I have removed two edits from this posting where it was indicated that SmsManager was added in API 19. I do not know what was changed in API 19, maybe something significant re sending SMSs, but SmsManager certainly predates API 19.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"
                        + phoneNumber)));
```

**Make sure you set `phoneNumber` to the phone number that you want to send the message to**

You can add a message to the SMS with (from comments):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));     
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks for your code. and i want to add, as i need to put my predefine text. I got this solution
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "sms:" + phoneNumber ) );

intent.putExtra( "sms_body", message );
startActivity( intent );

Comment: how to set "phoneNumber" from contact list?

Comment: @djk
thanks
i want to Read all contacts and want own page for sending sms with auto complete 
but i am not able to read contacts any good tutorial ?

Comment: I would use the default sms compose widget for doing it. just leave the phone number empty (it's optional)

Comment: @djk -How to add the  predefined text when sending via Whatsapp or Viber as well

Comment: Please, does anybody know if (and where) is this documented?

Comment: you can use this    @Mr-Moqadam                  public void sendsms(View view) {
        String phoneNumber = "+880xxxxxxxxxx";
        String message = "Welcome to sms";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: Hi. i want to send bulk sms. like 10,000  sms send at single click. Is it possible ? i heard android send 30 sms  every 30 minutes. plz help me

Answer (score 153):

This worked for me.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendSMS("5556", "Hi You got a message!");
           /*here i can send message to emulator 5556. In Real device 
            *you can change number*/
        }
    });
}

//Sends an SMS message to another device

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

You can add this line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Take a look at [this](http://androidprogramz.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-send-sms-in-android.html)

This may be helpful for you.

Comment: The question asks for showing the SMS in the standard compose view. This is the exact opposite, sending SMS behind user's back, no?

Comment: It fails to send message if there is apostrophe in it.

Answer (score 39):

Try the below code and then call, `sendSMS("99999999999", "message");` to send sms in desired number.

```
//---sends an SMS message to another device---
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    Log.v("phoneNumber",phoneNumber);
    Log.v("MEssage",message);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    new Intent(this, **DummyClasshere.class**), 0);                
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
}
```

Please place the following permission into `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Hope this might help.

**Update**
From the comment: 
DummyClasshere.class  is an activity without doing any process or the class in which u need to navigate.

> You can use Object.class in place of DummyClasshere.class.

Comment: something an activity without doing any process.or else the class in which u need to navigate..

Comment: I just use `new Intent()` and that does it.

Comment: how u know if message (sms) was sent?

Answer (score 28):

This will definitely  work, In this, Send message without using any intent .

```
SmsManager smsManager =     SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("Phone Number", null, "Message", null, null);
```

This code is used for **send message in background (Not showing message composer)**, It can also work inside the *Broadcast receiver*. If you want to send a message from Broadcast receiver.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: +1. Worked for my requirement. But I am missing one thing. This message does not appear in my sent items. Why is that so?

Comment: We have not used the default Inten process for sms sending, we are just using the Sms Manager. Intent will meet for maintaining the log of the SmsManager.

Comment: Yes. This is very useful to me. But the confirmation message given after sending sms means it could be better.

Comment: I would just recommend to add this block in try-catch.

Answer (score 10):

In Android , we have the class **SmsManager** which manages SMS operations such as sending data, text, and pdu SMS messages. Get this object by calling the static method SmsManager.getDefault().

**[SmsManager Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)**

Check the following link to get the sample code for sending SMS:

**[article on sending and receiving SMS messages in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)**

Answer (score 7):

I add my SMS method if it can help someone.
Be careful with smsManager.sendTextMessage, If the text is too long, the message does not go away. You have to respect max length depending of encoding.
More information here [SMS Manager send mutlipart message when there is less than 160 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348086/sms-manager-send-mutlipart-message-when-there-is-less-than-160-characters)

//TO USE EveryWhere

```
SMSUtils.sendSMS(context, phoneNumber, message);
```

//Manifest

```
<!-- SMS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

 <receiver
     android:name=".SMSUtils"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="SMS_SENT"/>
         <action android:name="SMS_DELIVERED"/>
      </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

//JAVA

```
public class SMSUtils extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SENT_SMS_ACTION_NAME = "SMS_SENT";
    public static final String DELIVERED_SMS_ACTION_NAME = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Detect l'envoie de sms
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SENT_SMS_ACTION_NAME)) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK: // Sms sent
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.sms_send), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE: // generic failure
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.sms_not_send), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE: // No service
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.sms_not_send_no_service), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU: // null pdu
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.sms_not_send), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF: //Radio off
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.sms_not_send_no_radio), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
        //detect la reception d'un sms
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(DELIVERED_SMS_ACTION_NAME)) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.sms_receive), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.sms_not_receive), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Test if device can send SMS
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean canSendSMS(Context context) {
        return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
    }

    public static void sendSMS(final Context context, String phoneNumber, String message) {

        if (!canSendSMS(context)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.cannot_send_sms), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(SENT_SMS_ACTION_NAME), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED_SMS_ACTION_NAME), 0);

        final SMSUtils smsUtils = new SMSUtils();
        //register for sending and delivery
        context.registerReceiver(smsUtils, new IntentFilter(SMSUtils.SENT_SMS_ACTION_NAME));
        context.registerReceiver(smsUtils, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED_SMS_ACTION_NAME));

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);

        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sendList = new ArrayList<>();
        sendList.add(sentPI);

        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliverList = new ArrayList<>();
        deliverList.add(deliveredPI);

        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sendList, deliverList);

        //we unsubscribed in 10 seconds 
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.unregisterReceiver(smsUtils);
            }
        }, 10000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
String message = "Hello World!";

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Include the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Some of what is explained above is meant only for placing an SMS in a 'ready to launch' state.
as Senthil Mg said you can use sms manager to send the sms directly but `SMSManager` has been moved to `android.telephony.SmsManager`

I know it's not **a lot** of more info, but it might help someone some day.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for **NOT** sending the SMS yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this can help u ...

Filename = MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


  Button click;
  EditText txt;
  TextView txtvw;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    txtvw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    click.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){


    txt.setText("");
    v = this.getCurrentFocus();

    try{
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage("8017891398",null,"Sent from Android",null,null);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        txtvw.setText("Message not sent!");
    }
    if(v != null){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(),0);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

add this line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This allows to send text message through existing app. phoneNumber - is String. If you do not wish to specify phone number, use empty string "".

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("smsto", phoneNumber, null));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "text message");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Send SMS from KitKat and above:-
ADD this permission in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

You should have to also implement the **runtime permission for Marshmallow** and Above Version.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.defaultmessanginggit">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ConversationListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ComposeSMSActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_compose_sms" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The code which will be the given below:-

**activity_conversation_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_send_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ConversationListActivity.java**

```
public class ConversationListActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    private int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS = 130;
    private Button btn_send_sms;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation_list);

        btn_send_sms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send_msg);

        btn_send_sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int hasSendSMSPermission = 0;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    hasSendSMSPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
                    if (hasSendSMSPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS);
                    } else if (hasSendSMSPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ConversationListActivity.this, ComposeSMSActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ConversationListActivity.this, ComposeSMSActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**This is code for sms layout and for sending SMS:-**

**activity_compose_sms.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_compose_sms.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/compose_to"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/composeEditTextTo" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/compose_message"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/composeEditTextMessage"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/compose_cancel"
                android:id="@+id/composeButtonCancel" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/compose_send"
                android:id="@+id/composeButtonSend" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/composeNotDefault"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/compose_not_default"
                android:id="@id/composeNotDefault" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/compose_set_default"
                android:id="@+id/composeButtonSetDefault" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ComposeSMSActivity.java**

```
public class ComposeSMSActivity extends Activity {

    Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_compose_sms);

        mActivity = this;

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compose_sms, container, false);

            rootView.findViewById(R.id.composeButtonCancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(getActivity(), new Intent(getActivity(), ConversationListActivity.class));
                }
            });

            rootView.findViewById(R.id.composeButtonSend).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String recipient = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.composeEditTextTo)).getText().toString();
                    String message = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.composeEditTextMessage)).getText().toString();

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(recipient, "ME", message, null, null);
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to send sms to any number:

```
 public void sendsms(View view) {
        String phoneNumber = "+880xxxxxxxxxx";
        String message = "Welcome to sms";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Update: if you use Intent to send sms, you don't need android.permission.SEND_SMS permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit tel number for letting user just choose from contacts, but inserting your sms text in the body. Code is for Xamarin Android:

```
    var uri = Uri.Parse("smsto:"); //append your number here for explicit nb
    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendto, uri);
    intent.PutExtra("sms_body", text);
    Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

where

Context is `Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity ?? Application.Context`

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Extension Function

```
inline fun Context.sendSMS(number: String, text: String = "", onCantHandleAction: () -> Unit = {}) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:$number"))
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", text)
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, null))
    } else {
        onCantHandleAction()
    }
}
```