# How to send SMS message on android device in the background? 

Tags: android, sms

in my app i need to be able to send a text message in a background, without users intervention. I am using SmsManager (code below) to accomplish that. It does send a message but the popup asking me to choose a delivery method still shows up (even after the message is sent). I do have Google Voice installed thus the popup. Is there a way for me to avoid displaying this popup while sending text message? Perhaps i shall use a different method?

Thanks!

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

**Update:** so just to see what will happen i selected a default delivery method being "text message" and check the box saying use this as default. Now when i send the message using the code above it sends it in the background but it also bring up the empty form to send a message to :| How do i get rid of this? :)

Comment: if i wanted to send the SMS in background even if the application is not running then do i need to create Service to make it run in background ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send SMS in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

restored the device and problem was gone, so must've been a third party app causing the send new message form, its all good now, sms is being send in a background. thanks for your help all...

Answer (score 1):

I tested that and didn't have that problem. I have Google Voice installed but only use it for voicemail on my main line so maybe thats it. Can I assume you have a separate Voice number? I think this is just an issue of Android not knowing which number to send the text from so you will have to pick a default the first time. Is there the option to set it as the default method? If your intention is the send this text secretly then maybe you might want to rethink your intentions for doing so.

Comment: yes i have a separate voice number via GV, but only for voice mail, and no i don't mean to send it secretly, user is very aware of this action. i just need to minimize the inconvenience. i know it's possible because i have third party app that does it right now so they must've done it somehow :)

Comment: @android-developer: Have you tried contacting the developer of the third-party application? Usually most don't mind offering some quick advice on something they've done.

Comment: @kcoppock: i don't think they will be willing to help as my app could be a potential competition to them down the road ;)

Comment: @android-developer: Never hurts to try! I've had good luck with the few devs I've contacted, they're usually very friendly. Probably depends whether it's a company or an indie dev, though.