# Stuck on issue, how to contact Google's android developer support?

Tags: android

I have a **[technical issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671564/how-to-send-sms-message-on-android-device-in-the-background)** that i am unable to find an answer to regarding android development. I tried posting it over here as well as google's [android-developers] mailing list. As of now i am stuck and unable to finish my application due to this problem. I certain that there is solution to my problem as i have seen at least one app doing what i need to do. My app is very unique and will be released on Android first, then iOS.

Is there a way to contact Google's android support team regarding my question or i should just abort my project?

**UPDATE:** here is a link to my question in case someone is able to help :)
[How to send SMS message on android device in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671564/how-to-send-sms-message-on-android-device-in-the-background)

Comment: Not the right place for this question, but what is your question that you are unable to solve here? Can you post the link?

Comment: @yogsma - thanks, i posted a link above, but here it is again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671564/how-to-send-sms-message-on-android-device-in-the-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to contact Google's android support team regarding my question

You already have, via StackOverflow and the `android-developers` Google Group. There are tens of thousands of Android application developers and a very small number of Googlers who try to assist them. That's why most answers are provided by the community.

> i should just abort my project?

Businesses often hire consultants to do more extensive research on issues they cannot resolve. There are any number of experienced Android developers who you might be able to hire to try to determine how best to solve your problem.

If, OTOH, your approach is "free help or forget about it"...

Comment: thanks for suggestions. do you have any idea how long does it take to get a question submitted/approved in [android-developers] google group? i posted mine three days ago and still haven't heard anything. do i get notified when its approved? or simply lack of response means nobody knows the answer to?

Comment: @android-developer: Yes, the Google Group is moderated, like most such groups, due to spam. Sometimes, they flush the moderation queue daily. Sometimes, it's a week or more. See if your post has shown up on the list or not.

Comment: i went through the list and it's not there so i assume it hasn't been approved yet. i guess i have to wait...

Comment: @android-developer: I don't keep track of when the queue gets flushed -- I just get a flood of inbox messages. I don't recall one in the past couple of days, though. Once your post shows up, you might want to "bump" it the next day, as your inquiry could easily get lost in the shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading over the [Android Community Page](http://developer.android.com/community/index.html), Also the android irc channel has been very helpful to me and there alot of experienced developers willing to help you in there(#android on freenode).  Another place would the android help chat here on SO.  On top of these there are TONS of forums out there you could try posting on.  I have never had a problem the community hasnt been able to help me figure out....goodluck!