# How do I send a SMS text message in the hidden background with current location data when the activity screen first loads on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, sms

I need to make an activity send a text message when it first loads on Android Studio. It's for a mobile safety app that automatically sends your location data to the police via SMS when the app first loads.

I'm trying the onStart method.

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{   

super.onStart();
}
```

How can I do it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send a text message without getting user permission and the same applies for assessing the location

Assuming that you had taken permission from USER and location is on

for sending the message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361428/how-can-i-send-sms-messages-in-the-background-using-android) 
and for accessing location on background [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535703/best-way-to-get-user-gps-location-in-background-in-android)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828639/get-gps-location-via-a-service-in-android)