# how implements code for sending messages to other device?

Tags: android, android-emulator

hi all how to implements code for creating a method for sending message to other device and

how can i use the sending message method in Activity class help me anyone of you overcome

from this problem (i mean first  write code in class and what code written that must be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this : [Send SMS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android)