# How to send sms when there is no gprs connectivity on android?

Tags: android, sms, send, gprs, connectivity

Is possible to send sms, only when there is no internet connection on android. I have gone through connectivity manager class thorough where i m able to send sms but each time, whenever 2G voice call started, or after switching on the phone. I wanted to send sms only when device goes to Airplane mode / Or Packet data disabled or Not internet pack .

Thanks....

Comment: You can sen sms only when network carrier is enabled at the situation where no internet is available. But you can`t send the sms when mobile is in airplane mode.

Comment: did you mean no network availability ?

Comment: check the following link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android

Comment: @lucifer, Specifically - i wanted to send sms when user disables his pocket internet or if there is not pocket internet at all on android device..

Comment: See basically there are two kinds of Network Tower, one is for Network Coverage & another one is for GPRS. so which one you are talking about ?

Comment: can you tell me how you can send SMS using GPRS ? are you talking  about any kind of web service for sending SMS ?

Comment: No, simply as in similar manner as it is by Sim.

Answer (score 1):

Or for the complete tutorial, go to the following link

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

With this, you will get the basic concept of sending sms message..After that you can modify it as according to ur requirement..

Comment: And, You cannot be able to send sms message when the device is in airplane mode, because at that time ur network carrier is not available..For sending sms message using this way, network carrier shoulkd be there..