# native messaging system in android

Tags: android, sms

I am just a starter and student researcher in android coding. I am thinking about writing an app that could access the native messaging app in phone. Is it possible to access the native messing app (accessing mean I could be able to send the message from native messaging app and read the incoming message)? How could I be able to read or reference about that topic? Thanks.

Comment: I think this one would be useful http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Comment: Along with @VladimirLichonos link, follow this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android

Comment: The question has not been properly answered yet. No mentions as to how one can access the 'native' sms app (without using SMSManager)