# How to send text in TextView through SMS?

Tags: android, sms

I improve my app with jokes and I have problem. I would like to add "`send by sms button`" and i would like to send text in `TextView` through `SMS` (If user choose joke and he will want send by `SMS`).

How Can I do that?

Comment: you can google it, to begin with

Comment: I'm looking for information in google but I didn't find

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [Send SMS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android). It is not possible to send Texts automaticly, Android secured that function. This code will start an Intent to the SMS send applicataion:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"
                        + phoneNumber)));
```

Also see [this tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) and [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/).

Comment: downvoted for very wrong information. SmsManager is what you use to send SMSs. Any app can ask the permission for that. (Which is more amazing is, your first tutorial link shows just that)

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Integrating SMS Manager Inside your App

#### Add permission in your manifest file::

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

---

```
 sendMySmsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
 sendMySmsBtn.setonclickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 public void Onclick()
   {
    sendSMS("99999999999", "message");
   });


  private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
   {        
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message,null, null);        
   }
```

### 2. Intenting SMS Application installed in your device

```
  int phoneNumber=9999999999; 
  Intent startSmsApp=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"
                    + phoneNumber);
  startSmsApp.putExtra("sms_body", message);
  startActivity(startSmsApp);
```