# Unfortunately Message Launcher has stopped

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am making a Android Program to *send appointment details* for future appointment, I have done my coding and getting everything but whenever i do click on Send button getting error message:

**Unfortunately Message Launcher [AppName] has stopped**

Manifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mamlambo.tutorial.sendmessage">
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mamlambo.tutorial.sendmessage.FormActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending sms on Button's click, you need to add `SEND_SMS` permission to your manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Also this post will help you, [Send SMS in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11642921/1626878)