# How to send SMS from .NET application with connected Sony Xperia

Tags: android, .net, smartphone, sony

I want to connect my Sony Xperia smartphone to the PC via USB and then I want to develop a .NET Application which uses the connected phone to send SMS with it. Is this possible?

Which components do I need?

Greetings
Christian

Answer (score 0):

You can consult to answer on this question for sending SMS:
[Send SMS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android)

For communication between PC & Mobile over USB, please check out Android USB documentation. It contains code snippet on how to achieve communication over USB.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html