# SMSlib analogue for Android phones

Tags: android, sms, smslib

Is there some solution that sends sms from PC via USB-cable-connected android phone? The ideal would be some android *.apk file + some desktop java API, similar to SMSlib (ideally, supporting the same methods but using own protocol instead of AT-command used by the smslib).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android tells how to do it android way.

Comment: the question is how to send sms via android plugged to pc but initiate the sms sending on the pc. and not only sms but ussd too