# Send SMS from within a service

Tags: android

I am trying to send SMS from within a service but the following error is thrown. The service Java file has been attached with the error code. Need assistance for the service as the service is not able o send the SMS.

I want to know if there is some way in which i can give permission to the service for sending the SMS or in any way i can complete the same.

```
 Sending SMS message: uid 10235 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
```

My Code is as follows :-

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(num1, null, sms_message+"", null, null);
smsManager.sendTextMessage(num2, null, sms_message+"", null, null);
smsManager.sendTextMessage(num3, null, sms_message+"", null, null);
```

My Manifest File is show below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Stack trace is there for you to read with understanding not for us to read it for you.

Comment: if you are testing on marshmallow or above, you have to request user to allow sms permission at runtime.You can send sms, only if the user grants permission

Comment: [Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650177/7557205)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure you have added uses-permission in the AndroidManifest.xml
Second if you target android 6.0 and above, make sure to have a look at Runtime Permission

Comment: I have added the SMS Permission to the manifest and i am having trouble sending SMS from the Service.

Comment: May I ask what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: I am using Marshmallow. Thanks got the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have not set the `android.permission.SEND_SMS` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.snazzyapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>


    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```