# How to combine Google Services with JavaFX multiplayer game?

Tags: javafx, google-play-services, javafx-8, google-play-games, javafxports

**Hi, I am writing a multiplayer turn-based game in JavaFX 8.**

For now I have game which is working on desktop and users connect by LAN network. I wrote a class for the client and another class for the server.
I am new in developing games by JavaFX and I know that I can compute my game with Google Services and there are ready-made tools for creating such multiplayer games.

This is link to Google Services: https://developers.google.com/games/services/

I would like to use Google Services because I want prepare game to porting with **JavaFXPorts mobile plugin** for  Desktop, Android and iOS.

1. Do I have to write client and server class again?
2. How should I add Google Services to each of systems?

Maybe anyone have any example of using Google Services in similar applications.

**Thanks in advance for all the answers and suggestions. :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaFXPorts, you can deploy your Java application to desktop and mobile devices, so if your client is a JavaFX application you won't need to write it again.

Surely you will need to take care about the different layouts required for different resolutions.

Since on mobile you will be running Java 7, make sure you don't use streams on your code. Lambdas can be used though.

Regarding the use Google Play Services, they work with JavaFXPorts. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155816/javafx-android-port-google-play-services).

But before going into Google Play Services, I will suggest you create some samples first, to get a grasp of the process.

Have a look at the free [Gluon plugin](http://gluonhq.com/products/tools/) to get you started with JavaFXPorts. Follow the samples and have a look at the list of [prerequisites](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_prerequisites) to be able to deploy your apps.