# Copying to the clipboard does not work on Android

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

Create a standard mobile application with this view:

```
public class DebugView extends View {

    ListView<String> console = new ListView<>();

    private DebugView() {
        setCenter(console);
        console.getItems().add("A");
        console.getItems().add("A2");
        console.getItems().add("A3");
        console.getItems().add("A4");
        
        var copyButton = new Button("Copy");
        copyButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            String log = console.getItems().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            var content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(log);
            Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(content);
            var message = new Toast("Copied to clipboard");
            message.show();
        });

        setBottom(copyButton);
    }
}
```

Run it on desktop and press the Copy button, you can paste the contents into a text editor.

Run it on Android and press the Copy button, you can't paste the contents into another app, like Gmail. Your previous copied content (if exists) will be pasted, so it appears that nothing is added to the clipboard, or that the clipboard is not available.

How to make `Clipboard` work on mobile?

Using

```
<javafx-maven-plugin-version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugin-version>
<gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.14</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>

<java-version>17</java-version>
<javafx-version>18.0.1</javafx-version>
<charm-version>6.1.0</charm-version>
<attach-version>4.0.14-SNAPSHOT</attach-version>
```

and graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final

Comment: I assume that you are using the latest GluonFX plugin and GraalVM? On iOS, that works fine, you can copy/paste from/to Gluon apps and third party apps, and input fields have ContextMenu support enabled by default. On Android, however, there are some issues. I'll look into it when time permits.

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes, I added the versions to the question. I don't have an iOS device to test on.

Comment: Android clipboard now should work with Attach 4.0.15-SNAPSHOT (See https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/pull/313).

Comment: @JoséPereda Great! I will test it and write the results here.

Comment: @JoséPereda The simple example is working now. Later on I will test my application which does some more work with the clipboard and see if everything is fine there. Thanks!

Comment: This works on my app as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Attach `4.0.14-SNAPSHOT` did not support Android clipboard. Version `4.0.15-SNAPSHOT` [added the functionality](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/pull/313) and `4.0.15` has been released with this support.

Comment: That’s correct, and you can also add that 4.0.15 has been released with such support.

Comment: @JoséPereda I added the info. If you want to write a more detailed answer feel free, I just didn't want the question to look unsolved.