# I want to send message in my android app but i don't want to use permission Send_SMS. I want to use Intent for send message

Tags: android

I want to send message in my app but i don't want to use permission (send_sms) in Manifest.

I want to use (Intent) for send message.

Answer (score 1):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"
                        + phoneNumber)));
```

[Send SMS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android)