# How to send Application installation friend request for app installation from mobile via sms?

Tags: android, google-api

I tried and researched invite friends to use application by entering their phonenumber and sending the invitation. While send refer friend by using google api it will ask from which mail id to send request then it will automattically get all the mail detais which is available in the circle of sender mail.The same way like is there any possibliity for sending app request via sms can anyone please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you searching for how to send an sms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send SMS in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android)

Comment: I'm not asking about send sms please read it above have edited .. How to send Application installation friend request for app installation from mobile via sms?   @aletede91

Comment: I think you can try using AppInvite like @marshallino16 suggests

Comment: Thanks @aletede91. Searched from AppInvite but there is no way to send application install request via sms there is only via gmail . Can you please search and let me know is der any other possible way is there

Comment: Reading Google documentation from AppInvite it seems it is possible send application install request via sms.

Comment: If u don't mind from where you get that detail colud you please share that link ..

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using **[AppInvite](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/)** to share app